# Next.js 'use client' with server component(glob)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, glob

Hi I want to make Gallery opacity 50% when I'm typing search bar.
But I feel I can't use 'use client' with **glob** library.

#### Following is my code

##### app/page.tsx

```
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";
import Gallery from "./ui/Gallery";
import SearchBar from "./ui/SearchBar";

export default function Home() {
  const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="max-w-5xl m-auto mt-10">
      <SearchBar setIsSearching={setIsSearching} />
      <Gallery isSearching={isSearching} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

##### app/ui/Gallery.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { glob } from "glob";
import Image from "next/image";
import { randomUUID } from "crypto";

const Gallery = async ({ isSearching }) => {
  let images = await glob("public/images/*");
  images = images.map((image) => image.split("public")[1]);

  return (
    <div className={`flex ${isSearching ? "opacity-50" : ""}`}>
      {images.map((image) => (
        <Image
          key={randomUUID()}
          src={image}
          width={300}
          height={300}
          alt="gallery image"
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

##### app/ui/SearchBar.tsx

```
import React from "react";

const SearchBar = ({ setIsSearching }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="w-full mb-4 border-2 border-gray-300 bg-white h-10 px-5 pr-16 rounded-lg text-sm focus:outline-none"
        onFocus={() => setIsSearching(true)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

#### Following is Error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Rc6.png)

I saw Next.js official document

1. DataFetching - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching
2. Rendering - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering

Answer (score 0):

Although, I found a answer(? may be bypass) from youtube,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwQs4wXr9Bg&ab_channel=JackHerrington

I answer my question for someone who might have a similar issue.

The new code get the images using **Route Handlers**.

#### app/page.tsx

```
import Image from "next/image";
import Gallery from "./ui/Gallery";
import SearchBar from "./ui/SearchBar";
import GalleryWrapper from "./ui/GalleryWrapper";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [isSearching, setIsSearching] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="max-w-5xl m-auto mt-10">
      <SearchBar setIsSearching={setIsSearching} />
      <Gallery isSearching={isSearching} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### ui/Gallery.tsx

```
import React, { use } from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

const getImages = async () => {
  let images = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api");
  return images.json();
};

const fetchedImages = getImages();

const Gallery = ({ isSearching }: { isSearching: boolean }) => {
  const images = use(fetchedImages);
  return (
    <div className={`flex gap-2 ${isSearching ? "opacity-50" : ""}`}>
      {images.map((image: string) => (
        <Image key={image} src={image} width={200} height={200} alt={image} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};


export default Gallery;
```

#### ui/SearchBar.tsx

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

const SearchBar = ({
  setIsSearching,
}: {
  setIsSearching: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        className="border rounded-md w-full mb-2"
        onFocus={() => setIsSearching(true)}
        onBlur={() => setIsSearching(false)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

#### api/route.ts

```
import { glob } from "glob";

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  let images = await glob("/images/*.png");
  return new Response(JSON.stringify(images));
}
```

Welcome your better idea or advice for sprout developer.